# Get the first html dropdown value using jquery to the text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

With my current code I am easily getting the html drop down values on change of the drop down using jquery but i am not getting default value which was selected in the drop down.

Here is what i tried jquery

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $("#dropval").change(function () {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        $("#data").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
        alert($("#dropval option:selected").text());
    });
});
```

and i tried the below code
`alert($("#dropval option:selected").text());` i am not getting the alert
[js fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/5bjrtfzc/1/)

Some times simple stuff also not working :)

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/5bjrtfzc/2/?

Comment: as the select is built, no option is selected. It shows by default the first option in the option list, without marking it as selected.

Comment: everything is working fine maybe you have disabled the javascript in your browser

Comment: hope this is what you meant [link](http://jsfiddle.net/LiranBo/5bjrtfzc/3/)

Comment: hi @LiranBo instead of option:selected can we give drop down name because as i have lots of option in my page

Comment: you mean on default? or always, you can use the option id number in a var. on load you can just use option at position 0

Comment: hi @LiranBo this is an simple part of my big HTML page where I have lots of dropdown fields are their if we write option:selected it was not working  can we give some for this

Comment: @Mahadevan, I'm updating my answer below

Comment: I try your fiddle link and it work normally @@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/LiranBo/rdv3or2x/) takes the value on load:

```
<select name="drop" id="dropval">
    <option selected value="first">First</option>
    <option value="second">second</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="data" />

$("document").ready(function () {
    $("#dropval").change(function () {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        $("#data").val($("#dropval").find("option:selected").attr("value"));
        alert($("#dropval option:selected").text());
    });
    console.log($(this));
    $("#data").val($("#dropval").find("option:selected").attr("value"));
});
```

**Option 2**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LiranBo/uj6jv83w/)

```
$("document").ready(function () {   
    $("#dropval").change(function () {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        $("#data").val(selectedValue);
        alert($("#dropval option:selected").text());
    });
    $("#data").val($("#dropval").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this possibility - getting the value of the previous selected option by using the `focus` event:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $("#dropval")
        .focus(function(){
            $("#data").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
        })
        .change(function () {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        //alert($("#dropval option:selected").text());
    });
});
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5bjrtfzc/4/

Comment: not on the focus on load itself it should get the value from the drop down

Comment: @Mahadevan then why did you put your code to get the value inside the `change` callback?